# Is it possible to replicate Flash banner to HTML5 CSS3 and JavaScript 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, banner

I just want to ask if I want to replicate or copy (100%) an animated web swf banner or flash banner file.... Is it possible to to be 100% copied.?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Depends on the banner.. A blind yes or no answer isn't possible.

Comment: This question is way to vague to be answered. SWF and HTML are different languages so there is no automatic way to copy the one into the other. However with javascripts similar visual representations can be achieved as in Flash(swf) so a replication may be possible - but this strongly depends on the actual banner

Answer (score 0):

Depend also of your tools.

If your are in Adobe ecosystem, Wallaby was the first Adobe attempt to do such things . Now, CreateJS is a library adopted by Adobe as a replacement for Wallaby, works as a plug-in inside Flash Professional and uses HTML5 Canvas for animations.
Other "free" tools:

- Google Swiffy that converts SWF files into HTML5, using SVG for graphics and JavaScript for animation
- Mozilla Shumway, a Flash virtual machine written in JavaScript.